# Ghost backend throws Proxy Error

Tags: apache, ubuntu, proxy, ghost-blog

I installed Ghost on a subdomain (http://blog.example.com) using Apache 2.4.7 as a Proxy on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

The blog is available on the subdomain, however when I try to access the backend with http://blog.example.com/ghost/editor/ I get a 502 Proxy Error:

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /ghost/editor/.

Reason: Error reading from remote server

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at blog.example.com Port 80
```

My Apache Virtual Host configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.example.com

    ProxyPreserveHost on

    ProxyPass / http://myVPS_IP:2368/

</VirtualHost>
```

Would appreciate your advise how to fix this.

Comment: Pls post back if you ever solved this. Am having the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.example.com

    ProxyPreserveHost on

    ProxyPass / http://myVPS_IP:2368/ Keepalive=On

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your url config in your Ghost's config.js?  Make sure it is set like this:

```
url: 'http://blog.example.com',
```

Comment: Yes, that has been changed before. Something is wrong with the Apache Virtual Host configuration. If you browse to any subfolders of the subdomain, e.g. http://blog.example.com/ghost/signin/, this is obviously not forwarded by Apache to the corresponding subfolders handled by Node.js.

Comment: Here is an example config that we use, maybe try this:(sorry paste looked horrible, here is a link) - http://www.allaboutghost.com/how-to-proxy-ghost-through-apache-for-security-and-multi-blog-setup/